# Jquery serialize & @RequestBody not working

Tags: jackson

Well I have gone through most of the questions regarding this topic in SO but not able to fix this issue.

My question is whenever I am using @RequestBody annotation within the below controller method, the ajax call never invokes this method but if I remove the @RequestBody annotation, the control comes in the method but having null values for contact object: Why the serialized form is not getting bind to the object?
and getting error: **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect**

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addContacts.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public String addContacts(@RequestBody Contact contact, HttpServletRequest request ) {

    return "success";
}
```

ajax call:

```
$("#add_more_contact").click(function(){
    var formJson = $("#addContactForm").serialize();
    $.ajax( {
        url : "/myproject/admin/addContacts.htm",
        type : "POST",
        data : formJson, 
        dataType : "text",
        contentType : "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert('Success - '+data);
        },
        error : function(xhr, desc, err) {
            alert("Desc: " + desc + "\nErr:" + err);
        }
    });
});
```

POST data in ajax request: these 4 variables are present in my Contact object.

```
firstName=bill&lastName=gates&email=&mobileNumber=
```

project-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Using jackson jar : jackson-all-1.9.9.jar

Not sure what I am missing??Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you include "Contact" class code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTTP 400 Bad Request` (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect) error occurs when the client did not send a syntactically correct entity.

In this case, the request body is expected to be a valid json, but it wasn't. As @Dave mentioned, your request does not contain a JSON, but a urlencoded string such as `name=stack&value=overflow`. Instead, it should be a JSON, such as `{"name":"stack", "value":"overflow"}`.

To achieve this, please refer to another good thread : [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery) .

A possible fix of your code:

```js
$("#add_more_contact").click(function(){
    var formJson = $("#addContactForm").serializeToObject(); // use plugin, or build by yourself
    // this variable should be a javascript object, 
    // such as {"name":"stack", "value":"overflow"}

    $.ajax( {
        url : "/myproject/admin/addContacts.htm",
        type : "POST",
        data : JSON.stringify(formJson),  // serialize javascript object to JSON 'string'
        dataType : "json",  // 'text' -> 'json'
        contentType : "application/json", // this can be omitted
        success : ...,
        error : ...,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks..Your suggestion worked..just made a sight modification by using .serializeForm() instead .serializeToObject()..both methods are doing the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

You're serializing as form data not json ... Build an anonymous map of your form data and pass that